# Set language with i18n an change country flag based on selected language in Vuejs

Tags: vue.js, vue-i18n

I'm a complete starter in Vuejs and I've done plenty of research before posting my very first question on this platform.

**Goal:**
When changing the language , the correct country flag appears next to the selector field.

**Tools:**
i18n
Vuejs

I've tried everything that I could think of but nothing seems to do the trick.
Would somebody mind putting me on the right track?

The country flags sit in my assets folder

1. belgian_flag.png
2. french_flag.png

   ```
   <template>
    <div class="locale-changer">
     <v-spacer></v-spacer>
    <select v-model="$i18n.locale">
      <option v-for="(lang, i) in langs" :key="`Lang${i}`" :value="lang">{{ lang }}</option>
    </select>
    <p>{{ $t('avatar') }}</p>
    <p>{{ $t('buttons') }}</p>
    <p>{{ $t('login') }}</p>
   </div>
   </template>

   <script>
   export default {
    name: "locale-changer",
    data() {
     return { langs: ["nl", "fr"] };
    }
   };
   </script>
   ```

   Languages files:
   nl.json

{
"avatar": "Dutch Speaker",
"buttons": "Knoppen",
"login": "Aanmelden"
}

fr.json

{
"avatar": "French Speaker",
"buttons": "Buttons",
"login": "Login Page"
}

Comment: can you add your language JSON sample file please?

Comment: and if possible a screenshot of what you want to achieve

Comment: @MARahman all I want to achieve is that when a language is choosen is that the language is changed to the selected language and that the flag of the country appears next to the language field

Answer (score 0):

This is how I do it - using a single JSON file with all localizations (each localization has a key `title` which represents the name of the locale in its corresponding language):

```js
<template>
  <pop-over>
    <flat-button class="country_selector pl-1 pr-1 pt-0 pb-0 ma-0 font-0 bold">
      <div class="current_flag" :style="{'background-image': 'url(' + $root.baseURL + 'flags/' + curLocale + '.png' + ')'}"/>
      <div class="flexbox flex-column align-center ml-1">
        <icon>
          <caret-up/>
        </icon>
        <span class="upper" style="margin-top: -5px;">{{ $root.locale }}</span>
      </div>
    </flat-button>
    <my-card slot="popover" title-class="popover_header">
      <!--
      <div slot="title">{{ $t('header.language_selector') }}</div>
      -->
      <div v-for="lang in $root.languages" :key="lang" v-close-popover class="popup_menu_item flexbox align-center pl-2 pr-2 pt-1 pb-1" @click="changeLocale(lang)">
        <icon :size="14" :color="($i18n.messages[$i18n.locale] ? lang === $i18n.locale : lang === 'en') ? '' : 'transparent'">
          <icon-checkmark/>
        </icon>
        <div class="country_flag" :style="{'background-image': 'url(' + $root.baseURL + 'flags/' + lang + '.png' + ')'}"/>
        <div class="flex-auto font-1 bold">{{ $i18n.messages[lang].title }}</div>
      </div>
    </my-card>
  </pop-over>
</template>

<script>
import { mapGetters, mapMutations } from 'vuex'
import iconCheckmark from '@/assets/img/icon/check.svg'
import caretUp from '@/assets/img/icon/caret-up.svg'

export default
{
  name: 'LanguageSelector',
  components:
    {
      iconCheckmark,
      caretUp,
    },
  computed:
    {
      ...mapGetters(['curLocale']),
    },
  methods:
    {
      ...mapMutations(['setLocale']),
      changeLocale (langCode)
      {
        this.setLocale(langCode);
        if (!this.$root.isLogged) return;
        const data = new FormData();
        data.append('language', langCode);
        this.$ajax(
          {
            method: 'POST',
            url: '/api/user/setusersettings/',
            login: this.$root.login,
            data,
          }
        );
      },
    }
}
</script>

<style lang="scss">
  @import '@/assets/scss/theme/footer.scss';

  .current_flag
  {
    border-radius: 50%;
    width: 24px;
    height: 24px;
    background-size: cover;
    background-position: center;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
  }

  .country_flag
  {
    border-radius: 50%;
    width: 22px;
    height: 22px;
    background-size: cover;
    background-position: center;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    margin-left: 4px;
    margin-right: 4px;
  }

  .country_selector
  {
    color: $footer_color;
  }
</style>
```

And the store mutation is

```js
      setLocale (state, lang)
      {
        state.locale = lang;
        document.querySelector('html').setAttribute('lang', lang);
        if (window.i18n) window.i18n.locale = lang;
      },
```

And Vue-i18n is instantiated like this

```js
import VueI18n from 'vue-i18n'
import locales from "./locales.json";

Vue.use(VueI18n);

window.i18n = new VueI18n(
  {
    fallbackLocale: 'en',
    locale: 'en',
    messages: locales,
    silentTranslationWarn: true
  });
```

The relevant computed properties in the root Vue instance are

```js
  computed:
    {
      baseURL ()
      {
        return process.env.BASE_URL;
      },
      locale ()
      {
        return this.$i18n.messages[this.$i18n.locale] ? this.$i18n.locale : 'en';
      },
      languages ()
      {
        return Object.keys(this.$i18n.messages);
      },
    }
```

Comment: Thank you for this very big answer. But this seems to be a very very complicated solution. Sure there must be a simpler way to get this done.

Comment: If this looks complicated then you should build your own solution step by step - first implement the drop-down list with languages, then make it actually switch the locale of `i18n`, then finally add the country flags. Remember - always attack complex problems by splitting them into smaller tasks. If some of the smaller tasks are still big and complicated - split them into even smaller tasks until each task becomes trivial.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is a bit old and you've probably already found a solution, but I got here 'cause I had the same problem and found a different approach to solving it, so I'm posting this in case anyone else has the same issue.

I made a folder called `locales` in my `src` folder which looks something like:

```
|--- src
     |--- locales
          |--- en-GB.json
          |--- fr-FR.json
          |--- de-DE.json
```

My `i18n.js` file looks like this:

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import VueI18n from 'vue-i18n'

Vue.use(VueI18n);

function loadLocaleMessages () {
  const locales = require.context('./locales', true, /[A-Za-z0-9-_,\s]+\.json$/i)
  const messages = {}
  locales.keys().forEach(key => {
    const matched = key.match(/([A-Za-z0-9-_]+)\./i)
    if (matched && matched.length > 1) {
      const locale = matched[1]
      messages[locale] = locales(key)
    }
  })
  return messages
}

export default new VueI18n({
  // These two lines are in case you want to setup environmental variables
  //locale: process.env.VUE_APP_I18N_LOCALE || 'en-GB',
  //fallbackLocale: process.env.VUE_APP_I18N_FALLBACK_LOCALE || 'en-GB',
  locale: 'en-GB',
  fallbackLocale: 'en-GB',
  messages: loadLocaleMessages()
})
```

Then I put it in my `main.js`

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import App from './App.vue'
import i18n from './i18n'

Vue.config.productionTip = false

new Vue({
  i18n,
  render: h => h(App)
}).$mount('#app')
```

Here comes my trick (don't know if it's considered a hack or anything, but it makes things simpler for me):

```
<select v-model="$i18n.locale">
  <option v-for="(lang, i) in $i18n.locale" :key="`Lang${i}`" :value="lang"
          v-on:click="$i18n.locale=lang">
      <img :src="require(`../assets/images/${lang}.png`)"></img>
  </option>
</select>
```

In order for the above code to work, make sure the names of the images are the same as the `locale` files, i.e. if your language file is called `fr.js`, the image should be called `fr.png`, and in my case, the image is called `en-GB.png`.

The `v-on:click`, will change your currently selected language. I've used `require()`, because in my case, it won't show the images without it (because of `webpack` if I'm not mistaken) - but you might not needed it. Test and see.

Hopefully this helps someone. Cheers!